# Nested JSON Response coming back as [Object] using FB.API?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

I know this is something really simple but for the life of me I can't figure out how to parse out the next level json request from this bit of javascript I'm writing in Node.js using the Facebook API.

Code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < userArrayLength; i++) { 

fb
  .api(usersArray[i] + '/posts?since=2017-05-17', { fields: ['from', 'id'], access_token: 'accessToken' }, function (res) {
    console.log(res, {depth: null});
  }); 


}     
  ;
```

My return has the following:

```
from: [Object],
id: 'postid_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
```

I know that all I need to do is step down on level in the JSON to from:name but I just can't get the formatting correct and can't find any good examples online.

I'm new to node and javascript so I'm sure its just something boned headed. Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(res));`

Comment: Progress! Yeah does indeed parse out both keypairs under 'from'. It return the user fb id and the name. Is there anyway that you know to select just the name keypair?

Comment: Use the dot notation . Get the name by res.from.name

Comment: [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) may be helpful here. To access the name property, you can just say `res.from.name`

Comment: Would I just parse out the results with JSON.parse() after I stringify it?